# Dell XPS 9343 two external monitors and built in display

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, dell, intel-graphics

On Windows 10, I was able to have two 4K monitors (Dell p2415q) daisy chained on one mini display port, and still use the built in monitor on my laptop.

On Ubuntu 18, I can not use the laptop display. When it will not even detect that I have two screens until I turn off the laptop display - then it works. This took a long while to discover.

Has anyone ever managed to use two monitors daisy chained and the laptop display? I have searched everywhere and no one mentions this. I am using core drivers, nothing special. Would the Xserv drivers help?